# How to send unique individual emails?

Tags: powershell

I need to send one unique email to different email addresses exporting 
them from a `.csv` file. I have a code but it just sends the message to all 
of the emails in one email.

```
#Import the file that store username and emails
$data = import-csv "C:.csv"

#Declare email content
$email = $data.Email | select -unique

ForEach ($email in $data)
{
$From = "***@gmail.com"
$To = $data.Email
$Subject = "Test"
$Body = "Test"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
}

#Sending email
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject `
-Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl `
-Credential (Get-Credential -Message "Please input valid credentials")
```

The code above works but as mentioned it sends just one email to all the email  addresses in the file. I need it to send one for each email.

Comment: Move your `Send-MailMessage` into the loop. Create a credential variable before the loop and assign it to the `-credential` param to stop it prompting each email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem I see in your code is that you first create an array of unique email addresses from the csv file in a variable `$email`, but later on you overwrite that same value by using it in the `foreach` loop.

There, in every iteration, the `$email` variable will become a complete row from the CSV file which is obviously not what you expect it to be.

Below a slightly adjusted version of your code. Note that I also used [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) to create a hashtable with all properties for the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet, to avoid having to use the easy to overlook backtick.

```
#Import the file that store username and emails
$data = import-csv "D:\mail.csv"

# Get a unique array of email addresses
$addresses = $data.Email | Select-Object -Unique

# Declare Credentials
$creds = (Get-Credential -Message "Please input valid credentials")

# loop through the email addresses array and send a mail to each of them
foreach ($email in $addresses) {
    $splat = @{
        From       = "***@gmail.com"
        To         = $email
        Subject    = "Test"
        Body       = "Test"
        SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
        Port       = 587
        Credential = $creds
        UseSsl     = $true
    }

    #Sending email
    Send-MailMessage @splat
}
```

<sup>Note that the `-Port` parameter is of type `Int32`, so you should not quote that</sup>

---

**Update**

As requested in your comment, if you want to use more fields from the CSV file, then the code would change.
Let's assume your CSV looks anything like:

> ```
> "User","Email","ManagerEmail"
> "Tom","t.somebody@yourcompany.com","el.jeffe@yourcompany.com"
> "Dick","d.somebody@yourcompany.com","el.jeffe@yourcompany.com"
> "Harry","h.somebody@yourcompany.com","di.rector@yourcompany.com"
> "Dick","d.somebody@yourcompany.com","el.jeffe@yourcompany.com"
> ```

(note, user Dick is duplicated)

Then the following will read the csv, deduplicate it on the Email property and send emails to each user:

```
# Import the file that store username and emails
# and uniquify the objectson property Email
$data = Import-Csv "D:\mail.csv" | Sort-Object -Property Email -Unique

# Declare Credentials
$creds = (Get-Credential -Message "Please input valid credentials")

# loop through the csv objects array and send a mail to each of them
foreach ($item in $data) {
    # every item is an object with properties .User, .Email and .ManagerEmail
    $splat = @{
        From       = "***@gmail.com"
        To         = $item.Email
        Cc         = $item.ManagerEmail
        Subject    = "Hi there {0}" -f $item.User
        Body       = "Test"
        SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
        Port       = 587
        Credential = $creds
        UseSsl     = $true
    }

    #Sending email
    Send-MailMessage @splat
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you! totally solved the problem, and the code looks better.

Comment: I have one more question actually, I have a User column in my CSV and would like to add each user id to their specific email message. Any idea on how this can be done?

Comment: @GerardoHernandezSanmiguel I have added new code to also use more fields from the CSV where needed.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, the script is just sending an email to the last row in the CSV file

Comment: Update: On my test CSV file I had the same email for the row EMAIL and MANAGEREMAIL it was sending just one email to the manager and cc the email that was duplicated in the manager and user.

Answer (score 1):

As per comments, please find the adjusted script and reasoning.

You were looping through the CSV but only sending the email once. It looks like it would have originally sent the email to ONE person, that being the last in your CSV.

This version will loop through and send an email for each line in the CSV.

```
#Import the file that store username and emails
$data = import-csv "C:.csv"

#Declare email content
$email = $data.Email | select -unique

# Declare Credentials
$creds = (Get-Credential -Message "Please input valid credentials")

ForEach ($email in $data) {
    $From = "***@gmail.com"
    $To = $email.Email
    $Subject = "Test"
    $Body = "Test"
    $SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
    $SMTPPort = "587"

    #Sending email
    Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject `
    -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl `
    -Credential $creds
}
```

Comment: Almost perfect, but you should use `$To = $email.Email` - otherwise you send `x` emails to **ALL** email addresses where `x` is the number of email addresses you have in the array. See my answer with the explanation

Comment: You are correct, I did not see that. Thank you my friend. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most important error you made is

```
$To = $data.Email
```

where you add all the emails to `To:` field. [Drew's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56520908/9902555) is almost what you want to follow but with one remark. Your `$To=` assignment should use `$email` which represents single object from array, instead of the whole array (which is `$data`).

```
$To = $email.Email
```

---

Edit: As [@Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) suggested in the comments, it's worth mentioning that the line

```
$email = $data.Email | select -unique
```

won't work as you use the same variable name later in `foreach` loop. What I'd suggest is to save unique email addresses to other variable

```
$uniqueEmails = $data.Email | select -unique
```

then iterate that one

```
# Change this
ForEach ($email in $data) {
# To this
ForEach ($email in $uniqueEmails ) {
```

And of course as you already saved `Email` propert to `$uniqueEmails`:

```
# This line
$To = $email.Email
# Should be changed to
$To = $email
```

Comment: But still, when using the `$email` variable again on the foreach loop as the leftmost variable, the line `$email = $data.Email | select -unique` does not make sense anymore and chances are you are sending emails to addresses that are duplicates in the csv file.

Comment: Thx @Theo - I just added a note about that